# how to plot two bar graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Qs

Use pandas to create a DataFrame that reports the number of graduates working at jobs that do require college degrees ('college_jobs'), and do not require college degrees ('non_college_jobs'). Assign this to a variable named df1.

my code

- DataFrame of college and non-college job sums

```
df1 = recent_grads.groupby(['college_jobs', 'non_college_jobs']).sum()
```

[image]

how can i correct the graph

Comment: You should provide a sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should reorganize your DataFrame in such a way that for each "other"
classification (men, women, full time, part time and so on) it contains just
**two rows**:

- first - for working at jobs requiring college education,
- second - for jobs which don't require it.

Then you should generate a bar graph from these data.

As an example, I took such a DataFrame, including classification by gender
and full/part time:

```
           College  No college
Job type                      
Men           3000        2000
Women         2500        2800
Full time     2800        2200
Part time     2700        2600
```

Note that the *Job type* is the **index**.

To generate the graph, you can run:

```
df.plot.bar(ylim=(0,4000));
```

getting the following picture:

[image]

I "moved up" the upper limit of *y* axis to *4000* (a bit above
the max. value) in order to provide enough space for the legend.
Otherwise the legend is superimposed on the top section of bars,
obstructing visibility.